# javac: file not found: Hello world.java

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to do my first Hello world project.
When I type:

```
javac Hello world.java
Error: file not found: Hello world.java
```

I made sure I search for it in the proper location and a proper name. I already set up jdk path in the environment variables.  I use Windows 10.

Comment: Please, put your code here.

Comment: you can't have spaces in a file name.

Comment: What @OldProgrammer said. You need quote your file name if you are going to use spaces or remove the spaces.

Comment: Class name and file name must agree `public class HelloWorld` and `HelloWorld.java`. Happy programming

Comment: Your class name and the file describing it should be `HelloWorld.java`, see [Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Java the filename should match the Class name. As there are no spaces in a class name definition, what you try to compile would have compilation errors even if you manage to instruct compiler to compile the file:

"Hello world.java" file should have at least a main method in

```
public class Hello world { //Compilation error at this point
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
}
```

Make sure that your class name including the main method is one word (e.g. Helloworld) and rename the class file to Helloworld.java
compile with

```
javac Helloworld.java
```

Run with

```
java Helloworld
```